# AsyncTask onPostExecute() sometimes is not called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsynTask to request data and update the UI, but when I call the task, sometimes the onPostExecute() is not called.

I added log, to check the execution flow and when onPostExecute is not called the last log is the one before the return of doInBacground() -->
And the app freezes
Has anyone experienced something similar?

```
    public class dataLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean> {    
        JSONObject token;    
        public dataLoadTask(JSONObject token) {
            if (token != null) {
                this.token = token;
            }
        }    
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
            JSONArray response;
            Boolean result = false;
            try {                    
                loadingData = true;
                response = NetworkUtils.schoolNotifications(token);                    
                notifications = parseResponse(response);
                Collections.sort(notifications, new NotificationsComparator());
                loadingData = false;                       
                JSONArray chatsJSON = NetworkUtils.schoolChats(token);                    
                chats = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < chatsJSON.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_chat = (JSONObject) chatsJSON.get(i);
                    Chat chat = new Chat(json_chat);
                    chats.add(chat);    
                }
                Collections.sort(chats, new ChatsComparator());                        
                result = true;                           
            } catch (Exception e) {                   
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                    
            return result;       
        }              
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {                
            if (result) {                    
                bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                        (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                                String fragmentTag = "";                                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                    case R.id.action_home:
                                        selectedFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                                        myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("notifications", notifications);
                                        myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("chats", chats);
                                        myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("schedule", schedule);
                                        fragmentTag = HOME_TAG;
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.action_subjects:
                                        selectedFragment = SubjectsFragment.newInstance();
                                        myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("notifications", notifications);
                                        myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("subjects", subjects);
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.action_tasks:
                                        selectedFragment = TasksFragment.newInstance();
                                        myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("notifications", notifications);
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.action_chats:
                                        selectedFragment = ChatsFragment.newInstance();
                                        myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("users", users);
                                        myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("chats", chats);
                                        fragmentTag = CHAT_TAG;
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.action_new_notification:
                                        selectedFragment = NewNotificationFragment.newInstance();
                                        myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("classes", classes);

                                        break;    
                                }                                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                                selectedFragment.setArguments(myBundle);
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment, fragmentTag);
                                transaction.commit();
                                return true;
                            }
                        });                   
                myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("notifications", notifications);
                myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("chats", chats);
                myBundle.putParcelableArrayList("schedule", schedule);
                myBundle.putBoolean("startup", false);
                Log.i("TESTTTTTTTTTTT", "9");
                HomeFragment activeFragment = (HomeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(HOME_TAG);
                Boolean homeActive = activeFragment != null && activeFragment.isVisible() ? true : false;
                if (!loadingNewData || (loadingNewData && homeActive)) {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    HomeFragment homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                    homeFragment.setArguments(myBundle);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, homeFragment, HOME_TAG);
                    transaction.commit();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    bottomNavigation.setEnabled(true);
                    profilePhoto.setEnabled(true);
                } else
                    loadingNewData = false;                
                ChatsFragment activeChatsFragment = (ChatsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CHAT_TAG);
                Boolean chatsActive = activeChatsFragment != null && activeChatsFragment.isVisible() ? true : false;
                if (chatsActive) {
                    activeChatsFragment.updateAdapter(chats);
                }                   
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }               
            loadDataProcessRunning = false;    
        }
    }
```

Logs:

```
12-22 12:23:27.916 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 01
12-22 12:23:27.916 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 1
12-22 12:23:29.549 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 2
12-22 12:23:29.560 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 3
12-22 12:23:29.668 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 4
12-22 12:23:29.668 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 5
12-22 12:23:29.669 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 55
12-22 12:23:29.669 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: true
12-22 12:23:29.681 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 6
12-22 12:23:29.682 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 7
12-22 12:23:29.682 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 8
12-22 12:23:29.682 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 9
12-22 12:23:29.682 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 10
12-22 12:23:29.683 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 11
12-22 12:23:29.684 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 12
12-22 12:23:29.684 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 13
12-22 12:23:29.748 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher/files/5 (No such file or directory)
12-22 12:23:29.876 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher/files/5 (No such file or directory)
12-22 12:23:29.881 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher/files/5 (No such file or directory)
12-22 12:23:29.883 15252-15257/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=23KB, data=30KB
12-22 12:23:29.884 15252-15257/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/art: After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=30KB
12-22 12:23:29.884 15252-15257/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
12-22 12:23:29.887 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher/files/5 (No such file or directory)
12-22 12:23:29.910 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher/files/5 (No such file or directory)
12-22 12:23:29.924 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher/files/6 (No such file or directory)
12-22 12:23:34.445 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/hwaps: JNI_OnLoad
12-22 12:23:35.168 15252-15257/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=52KB, data=60KB
12-22 12:23:35.169 15252-15257/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/art: After code cache collection, code=51KB, data=60KB
12-22 12:23:35.169 15252-15257/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
12-22 12:23:35.530 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-22 12:23:35.575 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/Choreographer: Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-22 12:23:35.886 15252-15279/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
12-22 12:23:36.899 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
12-22 12:23:38.361 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
12-22 12:23:41.346 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
12-22 12:23:41.361 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:41.361 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:41.372 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:41.372 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:42.755 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:42.759 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:42.759 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:42.766 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:42.766 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:44.760 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
12-22 12:23:44.841 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
12-22 12:23:46.033 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 01
12-22 12:23:46.034 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 1
12-22 12:23:46.059 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
12-22 12:23:47.798 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 2
12-22 12:23:47.808 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 3
12-22 12:23:47.820 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/Choreographer: Skipped 106 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-22 12:23:47.902 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 4
12-22 12:23:47.903 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 5
12-22 12:23:47.903 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 55
12-22 12:23:47.903 15252-15292/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: true
12-22 12:23:48.551 15252-15257/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=122KB, data=123KB
12-22 12:23:48.552 15252-15257/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/art: After code cache collection, code=100KB, data=86KB
12-22 12:23:48.644 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
12-22 12:23:48.655 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.656 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/Choreographer: Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-22 12:23:48.720 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 6
12-22 12:23:48.720 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 7
12-22 12:23:48.720 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 8
12-22 12:23:48.720 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 9
12-22 12:23:48.720 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 10
12-22 12:23:48.720 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 11
12-22 12:23:48.720 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 12
12-22 12:23:48.720 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 13
12-22 12:23:48.720 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.747 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.751 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.752 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.752 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.753 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.753 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.755 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.755 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.755 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:48.756 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:53.903 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
12-22 12:23:55.415 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
12-22 12:23:56.601 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:57.745 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
12-22 12:23:57.756 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:57.756 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:57.762 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:57.762 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:59.740 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
12-22 12:23:59.744 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:59.744 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:59.749 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:23:59.750 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-22 12:24:00.910 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
12-22 12:24:00.985 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwPointEventFilter: do not support AFT because of no config
12-22 12:24:02.687 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 01
12-22 12:24:02.687 15252-15298/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 1
12-22 12:24:02.707 15252-15252/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
12-22 12:24:04.603 15252-15298/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 2
12-22 12:24:04.611 15252-15298/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 3
12-22 12:24:04.703 15252-15298/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 4
12-22 12:24:04.704 15252-15298/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 5
12-22 12:24:04.704 15252-15298/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: 55
12-22 12:24:04.704 15252-15298/com.cathedralsw.schoolteacher I/TESTTTTTTTTTTT: true
```

The app freezes and the last log is from doInBackground()... No logs from onPostExecute() in the last call

Comment: Please run the program and paste the logs.

Comment: logs added.....

Answer (score 0):

Execute your `Asynctask` with `executor` if you android api version is more than 14.

Because in lower versions of Android all AsyncTasks were executed at single background thread. So new tasks might be waiting, until other task working.

In lower versions in Android (actually on pre-HONEYCOMB) you can't execute AsyncTask on executor.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
     task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
 else
     task.execute();
```

Before HONEYCOMB execute() method run AsynkTask in parallel.

Comment: Code added, and uses executeOnExecutor but the app works equal, freezes and not execute onPostExecute

Comment: @AleXis ok, from where you calling asynctask ?

Comment: from a fragment, the asyncTask is a class of the activity

Comment: in the fragment the call to the asyntask is ((MainActivity) getActivity()).loadData();

Comment: MainActivyty: https://expirebox.com/download/3db400d7d0e1127cb7c6f8837eab95f1.html